# Three quotes, thirteen anagrams

Tags: anagram

> "My flight from ___ just arrived at Heathrow. The connecting flight leaves in two hours. I will arrive at ___ Terminal 1. I'm going to take a taxi to my hotel if ___ not available at that hour. That said, I'm sure public transportation in Japan is miles ahead of what we have back home in the Balkans! Is it true that it often ___ night there? See you soon!"

> "I'm a big fan of ___'s work. Although he did not formally ___ an actor, he did ___ number of films. You have to respect his confidence, since cinema ___ form that requires very different skills than the music business."

> "As there is ___ of a deadly disease going around, people have been told to stay in their homes. People are stuck inside like ___ cage, including the imperial family in their summer house. The ___ has employed an ___ cheesemaker to prepare her desserts, but I don't think she's very happy with his services. Her daily ___ really amusing sight to witness – as long as you're is not at the receiving end yourself, of course!"

Fill the gaps with 13 different anagrams.

Comment: I grated the greenhouses of the lecherous czar on horseback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The quotes, with gaps filled:

> "My flight from _**TIRANA'S**_ just arrived at Heathrow. The connecting flight leaves in two hours. I will arrive at _**NARITA'S**_ Terminal 1. I'm going to take a taxi to my hotel if _**A TRAIN'S**_ not available at that hour. That said, I'm sure public transportation in Japan is miles ahead of what we have back home in the Balkans! Is it true that it often _**RAINS AT**_ night there? See you soon!"

> "I'm a big fan of _**SINATRA**_'s work. Although he did not formally _**TRAIN AS**_ an actor, he did _**STAR IN A**_ number of films. You have to respect his confidence, since cinema _**IS AN ART**_ form that requires very different skills than the music business."

> "As there is _**A STRAIN**_ of a deadly disease going around, people have been told to stay in their homes. People are stuck inside like _**RATS IN A**_ cage, including the imperial family in their summer house. The _**TSARINA**_ has employed an _**ARTISAN**_ cheesemaker to prepare her desserts, but I don't think she's very happy with his services. Her daily _**RANT IS A**_ really amusing sight to witness – as long as you're is not at the receiving end yourself, of course!"